# Create new list from list created from api response

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have some api request, I get response and parse some data in new list. List which I print is:

```
[u'2.40', u'2.35', u'2.67']
```

I need clear list as value:

```
[2.40, 2.35, 2.67]
```

How to do that ?

Comment: cast to `float`. `res = [float(x) for x in my_list]`

Answer (score 1):

In order to cast it into float, you can use list comprehension and create an new list with same items only now consist with float instead of strings.

```
l_str = [u'2.40', u'2.35', u'2.67']
l_float = [float(item) for item in l_str]
print (l_float)
```

You can do this with map as well:

```
l_str = [u'2.40', u'2.35', u'2.67']
l_float = list(map(float, l_str))
print (l_float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
item = [u'2.40', u'2.35', u'2.67']
new = [float(i) for i in item]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found resolution for this. If someone need:

```
lista_a = {u'total': 33455710208, u'free': 2834251776, u'used': 30621458432}

list = [list_a[key] for key in list_a]
```